# Azure SQL database costs much more than expected

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created an Azure SQL database with an estimated cost per month of €15,82. Some days later, my real cost is €36,- and my estimated cost is €243,-.

I only accessed the database a few times to the app in those few days (in development).

[Estimated costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsKr8.png)

Comment: What pricing model are you using? And what tier have you chosen?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL has several different pricing options; DTU, vCore and Serverless among others. The costs are calculated based on the chosen pricing model. In case of the Serverless model the resources used are of influence on the costs as well.

You can find more information at [Azure SQL Database pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database).

The estimated cost seems to look like the cost for an S4 database in the DTU pricing model.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for helping, my pricing model is Standard S0 : 10DTU. The linked page confirms it's € 15 by month. I don't understand why my cost is so high just few days after and with only some calls to the database (just crud operations to test an mvc app)

Comment: Do you have multiple SQL databases running? The pricing on the linked page is _per database_, not _per server_. Or do you have features set up that incur extra costs like additional storage, active geo replication or long-term retention?